# Clean Architecture and Paging 3.0 with Room

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, clean-architecture, android-paging

i am updating paging to version 3.0 and since i am using clean architecture ( the important thing here is the seperation between the core where i have my repos and my usesCases and the app module where all android framework classes ..) however i am using  two model classes (one for querying data from room for example :

```
 data class ExampleEntity(
    
        @Expose
        @ColumnInfo(name = INTERVENTION_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
        @SerializedName(INTERVENTION_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
        val interventionId: String?,
    
        @Expose
        @ColumnInfo(name = SITE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME)
        @SerializedName(SITE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME)
        val siteName: String?
    }
```

the other is to be used in the core module and useCase without implying the room database as dependency at all ...ex:

```
data class Example(

        @Expose
        @SerializedName(INTERVENTION_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
        val interventionId: String?,

        @Expose
        @SerializedName(SITE_NAME_COLUMN_NAME)
        val siteName: String?
    }
```

later in databseImplementation i map the Entity class to the core Class and it was possible in paging 2 as pagedlist can be mapped , now i can't seem to access the PagingData object of Entity and only can add to it (headers ,seperators...etc) how can i overcome this design puzzle ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the following [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-transform), it's possible to transform the items within PagingData before they reach your ViewModel.

In your Repository you should have something along the lines of this

```
val flow = Pager(PagingConfig(pageSize = 20)) {
  ExamplePagingSource(backend, query)
}.flow
```

The idea is to map the contents of `flow` like so

```
flow.mapLatest { pagingData ->
        pagingData.map { entity -> 
            // map to from ExampleEntity to Entity here
        }
    }
```

Comment: also have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70707468/4134215